# how to create the index from mongoose in elastic search in node,expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to create the index in elastic search with mongoose, express but there is no documentation available. I try mongoosastic but that is not comfortable.

So can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this module

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js

It's pretty simple to use and have a lot of documentation.

Just connect to DB-> get records that you need-> for each record run publish(client.bulk method).

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html

**EDIT**
Here is the example

`var es = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new es.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'error'
});
//doc is the mongoDB mocument
var bulkData = [{index: {_index: "yourIndexName", _type: "Any type", _id: doc._id}}, doc];
client.bulk({
   requestTimeout: 300000,
   body: bulkData
}, function(err, response){//final callback here});`

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks .i get it.but i have a problen on :                                                                                            client.bulk({
  body: [
    // action description
    { index:  { _index: 'myindex', _type: 'mytype', _id: 1 } },
     // the document to index
    { title: 'foo' },   actually i am not getting that how to add my db schema field  in this bulk operation.can u show me any example.thanks

Answer (score 0):

**this is working fine for indexing.so i have add the search query.my search query is like this**

```
 esClient.search({
            'index': 'product',
            //'q': '*'+searchKeyword+'*' this is searching query
            'body': {
                'query': {
                    'prefix': {'_all': searchKeyword}
                }
            }
        },function(err, response){ 
})
```

*But there is a problem .its searches only text based search not misspelled,auto correction,nearby,similar etc.i want to search query who is checked misspelled,similar,nearby all results.so plzz anbody help me.
thanks.*

Answer (score 0):

i have find a solution for misspelled searching and full text based near by searching.first i will define the fuzzy search for misspelling word.

```
 var searchParams = {
      index: 'product',
      body: {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
//search keyword is string which is searched
          "query": searchKeyword+'~',

        }
      }
    }
    };
esClient.search(searchParams,function(err, response){
})
```

**another searching for more like this ...............**

```
    "more_like_this": {
           "fields": [
             "productName","description","brand"
           ],
//searchKeyword is a string variable for searching
           "like_text": searchKeyword,
           "min_term_freq": 1,
             "min_doc_freq": 1,
           "max_query_terms": 12
         }
      }
    }
```

**if you want to fuzzy result then also try this**

```
var searchParams = {
  index: 'product',
  body: {
      query:{
      "fuzzy" : {
    "ProductName" : {
        "value" :         searchKeyword,
        "boost" :         1.0,
        "fuzziness" :     3,
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "max_expansions": 100
    }
}
  }
    }
    }
```